# How can Angular (gateway) get custom configuration from jhipster-registry-master?

Tags: jhipster, spring-cloud-config

I am evaluating the JHipster microservices architecture.

Where do I need to write my application specific configuration in jhipster-registry-master?

How can I get this configuration from Angular (gateway) and from Java (Microservice)?

Is there any documentation/example?

Answer (score 0):

For java spring-boot, this is documented in [Spring Cloud Config Server docs](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html) you have to choose either filesystem backend or git backend (but not jhipster-registry-master), for the angular part you could consume a REST resource on your java backend exposing a part of your configuration (you can see an example in ProfileInfoResource.java)